# VueJS nested components: Best practice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm a newbie in VueJS.2 and today working with VueJS Components.

So, I ended up with this `.vue` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="apps">
    <ul class="icons">
      <li v-for="app in apps" class="app" :style="style">
        <div :class="icon(app)"></div>
        <div class="name">{{app}}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'desktop-apps',
    data () {
      return {
        apps: ['Txt File', 'Img File', ...],
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }
    },
    methods: {
      icon (name) {
        return 'icon ' + name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_')
      },
      style () {
        var _top = this.top
        var _left = this.left
        return 'top:' + _top + 'px;left:' + _left + 'px;'
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  // li has position:absolute and vertically rendered
</style>
```

This Component works well...

I want to know that this code is good or can be improvised (via `compute` or something else?
If YES, then HOW?

Also, I want to clarify 2 more questions:

1: how can I get the `height` of `ul.icons`, so that, if children `li.app`'s overall height is greater, than update the `top` & `left` style from `style method`.

2: How to add and re-style `app` (`li.app`) from external component?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Your first question (*"[is] this code is good[?]"*) is probably too broad. This website is for more specific questions, like your second two questions.  But it may be a good idea for you to create two separate questions on this website for those second two questions, so that it's easier for people in the future to search for them by their titles.

Comment: @NathanWailes: Thanks for your suggestion about separate threads, but these 2 questions are inherited from the code of this thread, so I asked here. Anyways, I'll take care of this for next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can pet a `ref` on the `<ul>` like this `<ul class="icons" ref='icon'>`

and then return the height:

```
this.$refs.icon.offsetHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually style goes into computed and can be returned as JSON to improve readability e.g

```
computed: {

  style () {
    
    return { 'top': this.top, 'left': this.left } 
  }
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Priority-A-Essential

Best of luck